# Scala: Weird result from 'if' statement

Tags: scala, if-statement

Trying to use kind of Scala 2.10.3 'conditional' statement I do:

```
scala> val index = "male-names"
index: String = male-names

scala>  val kind = if (index == "male-mames") "mn" else "fn"
kind: String = fn
```

***Why 'kind' gets "fn" value instead of "mn"?***

On the other hand the following still holds:

```
scala> index == "male-names"
res28: Boolean = true

scala> index
res29: String = male-names
```

Comment: Do you have typo? `if (index == "male-mames")`

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me, sorry to interupt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> val index = "male-names"
index: String = male-names
```

there is a little typo error

```
scala>  val kind = if (index == "male-mames") "mn" else "fn"
                                      ^
kind: String = fn
```